# Where do people pronounce "ank" as /eŋk/ vs. /æŋk/?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, dialects

Let's use "bank" as an example.  Some Americans pronounce it /bæŋk/, using the vowel of TRAP.  Others pronounce it /beŋk/, using the vowel of FACE.

Where are these two pronunciations found?

Comment: Well, it's a feature of what's called the Northern Cities Vowel Shift in the United States. In dialects undergoing this shift (still going on in the inner cities of the N.E. USA), the woman's name _Ann(e)_ is often confused with non-dialectal pronunciation of the man's name _Ia(i)n_, both as /'iyən/ ['ʔijɨn].

Comment: @Josh61, I am not.  The pronunciation I'm referring to is further forwards and more raised than either example at that link, pronouncing "bank" with the same vowel as "bane".

Comment: I would never have imagined that anyone anywhere used the *ban* vowel in *bank* rather than the *bane* vowel.  There are no common words ending in *-enk* to contrast with the many that end in *-ank*.

Comment: @Joe: Well, it wouldn't sound like that. That's a different environment. The pattern is different from the Great Vowel Shift, where only long vowels changed position. This applies to most American English vowels, but not always the same way. [Here's the chart](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2VowelShifts.pdf) for both vowel shifts.

Comment: OP: Archaic forms like *blenk, renk, venk* have all been respelled as *blank,  rank, fang*, while ones like *clenk, enk, kent* have all turned into *clink, ink, rink*. I don’t think you will find enough distance between the three /æŋk, eŋk, iŋk/ sounds to support all three of those as phonemically distinct sequences. @JohnLawler: The only quasi-[en]-like sequence I can think of at/near a word’s end is in some speakers’ pronunciation of *orange* as [ˈɔɻʷẽʒ] — which I may be misapprehending myself. Maybe *bang* counts, though.

Comment: I pronounce it that way. I'm from mid-Michigan. Pretty normal around here. By the way, I asked a similar question before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90681/pronunciation-of-bank-tank-etc-bay-nk-ray-nk-or-baen-k-or-raen-k

Comment: @Joe I know: you are saying that *bank* has the TRAP vowel not the FACE vowel. I would never have thought of it that way; I think that [in my accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Midwest_American_English), it has to be the FACE vowel. This might be the “apparent” *bag–beg* merger (which isn’t, but anyway), which I never thought I had. I didn’t realize it was considered part of the GNC vowel shift. (Native accent: Milwaukee area.) **Do please note that the nasal following it will mutate the vowel somewhat anyway, which is why I did *not* use BAN or BANE for my lexical sets.**

Comment: Before nasals, especially, the distinction between lax front vowels is very weak. Americans often can't distinguish _pin_ from _pen_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, but I am not one of the *pin–pen* people; I should have the same accent as you do, or near enough as to make no difference. I guess though the nasal-muddies-it-effect is why I couldn’t see a lot of distinction between /æŋ, ɛŋ, ɪŋ/, and I am frankly surprised that others can. :(

Comment: I rather wish you would not phrase it in terms of “long a” versus “short a”; I find those terms extremely confusing.  Those are Hooked-On-Fonix™ terms used to teach six-year-olds, not something internationally understandable like IPA. Even lexical sets would be better. But I have never heard **anyone** say *bank* the same way  as *Ban Ki-moon* starts, as you apparently do (and as the OED also reports).  It is strange. Maybe we are only thinking we hear things.

Comment: @tchrist, I agree about the nature of "long-a" terms, just wanted something for non-IPA-savvy folks.  My experience is the opposite of yours: *bank* goes with TRAP, hearing it with FACE was quite surprising.

Comment: I strongly suspect your answer is to be found here, starting from where they talk about [/æ/ tensing in environments that vary widely from accent to accent.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_English)  It specifically says, in bold: **Nearly all American English speakers pronounce /æŋ/ somewhere between [æŋ] and [eɪŋ], though Western speakers specifically favor [eɪŋ].** Where are you from that this should surprise you?

Comment: Now that's throwing me off even more.  /æ/ tensing is in my own dialect, but never before /ng/.

Comment: Like tchrist, I don't think I've ever heard *bank* with TRAP.  John Lawler says it's a Northern thing, but everyone down South (in both SAE and AAVE) uses FACE and I think we'd interpret a TRAP vowel as a Northern pronunciation (rightly or wrongly).

Comment: So is TRAP *bank* a northern pronunciation or a southern one?

Comment: If you are talking about American accents, could you edit in the [american-english] tag? Because in British English, *bank* **is** pronounced as in "Ban Ki-Moon" /bæŋk/, and a real clipped British RP can make *bank* into /beŋk/ which can sound a bit like /beiŋk/ (although I've never heard it go **that** far).

Comment: You're talkin about one of the vowel changes ([æ]➝[e]) in the Northern Cities Chain Shift (p.2 of [the handout linked here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2VowelShifts.pdf); p.1 is the Great Vowel Shift, separating Middle from Early Modern English).

Comment: @JohnLawler, this particular vowel change appears to be far more widespread than the Northern Cities Shift.

Answer (score 5):

I think the pronunciation /beŋk/ is found all over the U.S. (although certainly lots of Americans say /bænk/). We have comments saying that it occurs in the Northeast, the South, the Upper Midwest, and the West. I know it's also found in the Midland accent (the lower Midwest). What proportion of speakers use it probably varies regionally, but I don't know if any studies have been done on this.

I also don't know how old this feature of the American accent is, but judging from how widespread it is, it must be fairly old.

See also [this](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/11/bank-balance.html) blog entry.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_English) says it happens in California English, but I believe it's much more widespread in the U.S. than that.

Comment: I don’t usually do this, but Peter, that’s a really fascinating blog entry, so thanks very much for sharing.

Comment: When you say "this pronunciation", do you mean /eŋk/ or /æŋk/?

Answer (score 0):

I often heard the pronunciation **/æŋk/** growing up in Connecticut. I hear it less often now, though in fairness I no longer live there... Still, I do hear it once in a while when I'm in town.

Comment: When you say "this pronunciation", do you mean /eŋk/ or /æŋk/?

Comment: Apologies. I mean /æŋk/.